# Bash pairwise array expansion

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have two arrays of same lengths like following:

```
arr1[1]=2
arr1[2]=5

arr2[1]=x
arr2[2]=y
```

I am trying to create a string like "`2 x 5 y`".

Since the length of the arrays can be a variable, is there any way to do this without using a loop and string concatenation (like parameter expansion or something) ?

Comment: You can use loops even when the array lengths are varying

Comment: That's what I meant. I can use loops. But I want to know if there are any other tricks like expansion to avoid loops. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste` with **process substitution**:

```
arr1[1]=2
arr1[2]=5

arr2[1]=x
arr2[2]=y

s=$(paste <(printf "%s\n" "${arr1[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${arr2[@]}") |
    tr '[[:space:]]' ' ')
echo "$s"
2 x 5 y
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. One quick question, with `tr`, are you removing extra space? Because it seems to work even without the `tr`.

Comment: Yes I am just removing extra whitespaces (space/tab/newlines) etc with `tr`. You can skip it also.